# d3.js, I want to add the data values in the json

Tags: json, d3.js

I am using d3.js.
Create and want to make total energy values in the files json.
Should I use the nest () function?

```json
[
{"name":"a","energy":200},
{"name":"b","energy":400},
{"name":"c","energy":450},
{"name":"d","energy":300},
{"name":"e","energy":120}
]
```

Comment: @Cœur Could you fill me in on the edit you made? Just curious.

Comment: @altocumulus, go to [the list of revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41563698/revisions), take [a revision before my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41563698/2), copy-paste the title in [a tool that can escape invisible characters](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/), tap "convert" and you'll see "_d3.js, I want to add the data values &#x200B;in the json_". I have removed that `&#x200B;` (zero-width space) from the title.

Comment: @altocumulus I've reported the bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317953/infrequent-data-corrupting-bug-when-writing-values

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. I suppose that you want to add a new property with the total to each object... In that case, use a `forEach`:

```js
var data = [
{"name":"a","energy":200},
{"name":"b","energy":400},
{"name":"c","energy":450},
{"name":"d","energy":300},
{"name":"e","energy":120}
];

var total = d3.sum(data, d=> d.energy);

data.forEach(d => {
d.total = total;
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```